# Find Next / Previous Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading data via ajax from a row of divs with a class of .gameListing. When one of the divs is clicked it has a class of .active added and loads the relative data into a container, this is all working perfectly.

What I would like is to have a Previous & Next link which finds the next or prev .gameListing and clicks it.

```
$('.gameListing').click(function(){

    $('.gameListing').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    call_ajax(url);
});




function call_ajax(url) {

    $.ajax( {
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            data: {json:  1},
            dataType: "JSON"
     })

        .done(function( data ) {

        // LOAD GAME INFORMATION
        $("#game-name").html(data.post.title);
        $("#game-reels").html(data.post.custom_fields.reels);
        $("#game-paylines").html(data.post.custom_fields.paylines);
        $("#game-minBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.min_bet);
        $("#game-maxBet").html(data.post.custom_fields.max_bet);
        $("#game-jackpot").html(data.post.custom_fields.jackpot);
        $("#game-info").html(data.post.custom_fields.game_info);

        // LOAD GAME PROVIDERS
        var provSource = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
                provSource = provSource.replace(/ /g,"-");
                $("#game_provs").load("http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + provSource + "/ .gameBox-Ops");

        // LOAD GAME THUMBNALS
        var gameThumbSrc = new String(data.post.custom_fields.game_name);
        gameThumbSrc = gameThumbSrc.replace(/ /g,'');

        $('#gameBoxGallery').html('');
            for(i = 0;  i<= 2; i++){
                            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-' + i + '.jpg" class="gameThumb">'
                            $('#gameBoxGallery').append(image);
        };

        // ZOOM FIRST THUMBNAIL
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').html('');
            image = '<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/games/screenshots/' + gameThumbSrc + '-0' + '.jpg" id="gameScreenshot">'
        $('#gameBox-Screenshot').append(image);

        })  
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: What's your HTML structure like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$('.prev').click(function(){

    var $current = $('.gameListing .active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    $current.prev().addClass('active');

    var id = $current.prev().attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    call_ajax(url);
});

$('.next').click(function(){

    var $current = $('.gameListing .active');
    $current.removeClass('active')
    $current.next().addClass('active');

    var id = $current.next().attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    call_ajax(url);
});
```

UPDATE

If you want to use a generic function:

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
     Navigate('previous');
});

$('.next').click(function(){
     Navigate('next');
});


function Navigate (direction){
    var $current = $('.gameListing .active');
    $current.removeClass('active')

    var secondItem = $current.next().addClass('active');
    if(direction == 'previous')
         secondItem = $current.prev().addClass('active');

    var id = secondItem.attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    call_ajax(url);

}
```

Comment: To prevent repetition, you could use 1 function that take a string as argument.

Comment: Perfect solution, although does need to be .gameListing.active without space between. Many thanks

Comment: Your update looks great, however the prev link seems to add active class to next as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can use .next() from Jquery

for more detail https://api.jquery.com/next/ & for Previous use .prev()
https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for if your `.gameListing` are not next to eachother (so if `next()` and `prev()` won't work):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7z9b5st/) for if the code snippet doesn't work.

```js
jQuery.fn.reverse = function() {
    return this.pushStack(this.get().reverse(), arguments);
};
function GameListing(el) {
    $('.gameListing').removeClass('active');
    $(el).addClass('active');

    var id = $(el).attr('data-id');
    var url = "http://localhost:8888/projects/superfreerespo/" + id + "?json=get_category_posts&slug=games";

    //call_ajax(url);
    $('#result').text('URL: ' + url);
}
$('.gameListing').click(function () {
    GameListing(this);
});
$('.prev').click(function () {
    var next = false;
    $('.gameListing').reverse().each(function () {
        if (next) {
            GameListing(this);
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            next = true;
        }
    });
});
$('.next').click(function () {
    var next = false;
    $('.gameListing').each(function () {
        if (next) {
            GameListing(this);
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            next = true;
        }
    });
});

function call_ajax(url) {
  // Your code here
}
```

```css
div {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}
div.active {
    background:green;
}
#result {
    background:red;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev">&laquo;</div>
<div class="gameListing" data-id="1">1</div>
<div class="gameListing" data-id="2">2</div>
<div class="gameListing" data-id="3">3</div>
<div class="gameListing" data-id="4">4</div>
<div class="next">&raquo;</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a commented `call_ajax` function in your answer?

Comment: The actual ajax won't work in this example, it will just throw an error.

Comment: So, remove it from the answer.

Comment: No. It's the OP's code. To make it work all he would need to do it uncomment it and the line of code to call it. Removing it would not make the post more readable at all.

Comment: It will. On mobile devices, the code block isn't scrollable. If it's an exact copy, I'd do something like: `call_ajax(url){ /* Your code here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using custom data attribute

```
var $current = $('.gameListing.active');
$current.removeClass('active')

var postNumber = parseInt($current.attr('data-count'));

var nextPost = (postNumber - 1);

$("[data-count='"+nextPost+"']").trigger("click");
```